# Trying access the view from the method, but not able to access,

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I'm new to laravel

here call method will call another method. But in that method I'm unable to make view(), I'm not getting errors, nothing. It's just a blank page.

I tried like this

Route:
`this is the route,  Route::get("controller/{method}/{any?}", [Shop::class, 'call'], function(){ });`

class:

```
`class Shop extends Controller{

   public function call($request, $param=null){

        if($request){

            $method = $request;
            
            if(method_exists($this, $method)){

                 $this->$method();
            }else{

                echo "{$request} does not exists.";

                return redirect('/');
            }
        }

    }

        protected function dashboard(){

            echo 'dashboard works...';
    
            return view('dashboard'); //dashboard.blade.php

        }

       protected function main_menu(){

            echo 'dashboard works...';
    
            return view('main-menu'); //main-menu.blade.php

      }
       
      similarly other methods...
      Here the problem is, nothing is loading, except a blank white page.
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

change your route to
 `Route::get('controller/{method}/{any?}", [Shop::class, 'call']);`
and Be sure that route ("/") is available

Answer (score -2):

```
 class Shop extends Controller{

   public function call(Request $request, $param=null){

        if($request->method){

            $method = $request->method;
            
            if(method_exists($this, $method)){

                 $this->$method();
            }else{

                echo "{$method} does not exists.";

                return redirect('/');
            }
        }

    }

        protected function dashboard(){

            echo 'dashboard works...';
    
            return view('dashboard'); //dashboard.blade.php

        }

       protected function main_menu(){

            echo 'dashboard works...';
    
            return view('main-menu'); //main-menu.blade.php

      }
       
      similarly other methods...
      Here the problem is, nothing is loading, except a blank white page.
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers